# How to do the Modification for this requirement? and where to do?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the sample below I add some sample file, which is working fine but I need to do some modification on that.  Currently while validating, it shows the error like this:
[image]

But what I need it to do is to show a tooltip.  The tooltip needs to be auto pop and remain visible until the error is cleared.  Like this:
[image]

```js
$('#myForm').validator()
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/dist/validator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Cina Saffary" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="inputTwitter" class="control-label">Twitter</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
      <input type="text" pattern="^[_A-z0-9]{1,}$" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="inputTwitter" placeholder="1000hz" required>
    </div>
    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="help-block with-errors">Hey look, this one has feedback icons!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <input type="password" data-minlength="6" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
      <span class="help-block">Minimum of 6 characters</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Whoops, these don't match" placeholder="Confirm" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
        Boxers
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
        Briefs
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="terms" data-error="Before you wreck yourself" required>
        Check yourself
      </label>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hiring coders is hard these days

Comment: Am Beginner for designing...

Answer (score 3):

Many ways of doing this.

With pure CSS, leaving the DOM structure alone:

```
span.help-block.with-errors {
    position: absolute;
    top:45%;
    right:36px;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Or, if you modify the DOM structure (moving the validation text into the `.form-group`):

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="inputTwitter" class="control-label">Twitter</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
        <input type="text" pattern="^[_A-z0-9]{1,}$" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="inputTwitter" placeholder="1000hz" required>
        <span style="position:absolute;top:2px;right:36px;z-index:1000;" class="help-block with-errors">Hey look, this one has feedback icons!</span>
    </div>
    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

You could inline a bit of CSS to get the position correct. Stack snippet follows.

If you want to do the tooltip-style thing, I'd suggest a jQuery plugin to handle this bit for you. One example is [Tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/).

```js
$('#myForm').validator()
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/dist/validator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Cina Saffary" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="inputTwitter" class="control-label">Twitter</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
      <input type="text" pattern="^[_A-z0-9]{1,}$" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="inputTwitter" placeholder="1000hz" required>
<span style="position:absolute;top:2px;right:36px;z-index:1000;" class="help-block with-errors">Hey look, this one has feedback icons!</span>
    </div>
    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <input type="password" data-minlength="6" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
      <span class="help-block">Minimum of 6 characters</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Whoops, these don't match" placeholder="Confirm" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
        Boxers
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
        Briefs
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="terms" data-error="Before you wreck yourself" required>
        Check yourself
      </label>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you help me for last image sample?

Comment: This one working fine.. like that auto pop up... until clear error it need to be show...